# the meaning of てませんか in this sentence

Tags: negation, particle-か

> 俺は恵子に何も感じてないので　男女の関係は一切ないです

I don't have any feelings toward 恵子, so our relationship isn't one of a man and a woman

> 確かに...

That's true/etc.

And then he answers:

> 疑ってませんか?

I'm confused by the answer. Is this "Won't you doubt me?" or more "Don't you have doubts"? or more "You are not doubting me"?

He tells the character his relationship with Keiko is platonic and the other character accepts it.

But I don't get his answer.

Comment: I am not certain, but wouldn't "don't you have doubts?" mean something similar to "are you sure [of what you've just said/you don't have any feelings towards her] ?"

Comment: `確かに。` (with full stop) is like "That's true", but `確かに...` (with ellipsis) can sound like "It may be true...", "True, but..." or "I know...", and that's why he thought the listener might not be fully convinced.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this:

> A: 俺は恵子に何も感じてないので　男女の関係は一切ないです 
> B: 確かに... 
> A: 疑ってませんか?

This is fairly common. Negative questions in Japanese sometimes are kind of like echo questions in English. They don't mean "Is it the case that you aren't doubting me...?", but "You are doubting me, aren't you?".

You can see the link between these two meanings pretty easily. Asking with a question with a negative verb implies that you think that the positive statement is the case. "Don't you have to go to school today?" (The speaker thinks that you had to go to school).

A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=so7BXOwSyEU) with more confusing examples.